# Is it possible to update my iPhone 3G without a computer?

Tags: software-update, iphone

I want new the new update for my iPhone 3G (used as an iPod) but do not want to mess anything up. Can I update it without a computer? I also have no SIM card for the phone.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't — you need a computer. Over-the-air updates were introduced in iOS 5. As the iPhone 3G can't run iOS 5, you can't do OTA updates, and therefore you need a computer to update it.

Also, 'the new update' (I presume you are referring to iOS 7) isn't compatible with the iPhone 3G, regardless of how you update.

Answer (score -2):

No but there is a way you can update to iOS 7 how cool I haven't dun it though

Comment: No you cannot install iOS 7 on iPhone 3G via the APPLE servers, the other way to do is whited00r, which simulates it to look like iOS 7. Also this is not an answer to the question asked.